# What is the most dangerous area of Los Angeles (or its suburbs) according to police statistics?

Tags: usa, safety, security, california, los-angeles

I will be travelling to L.A. soon and I am wondering which areas should be avoided to stay safe. Are there official no go zones? Do you maybe know of any maps?

Comment: Questions about safety are usually opinion based and therefore off topic here. The chances for being shot by the police as a non-criminal bystander are significantly higher in the USA as in most other comparable countries, so if you are easily enough scared, you might want to avoid the USA in general, and not only specific neighbourhoods in Los Angeles.

Comment: The LA times offer a crime map. http://maps.latimes.com/crime/

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thank you for your answer. I thought if there is something like official recommendations or maps based on crime statistics that wouldn't be based on opinion... Avoiding this trip is not an option for me.

Comment: Safe from what? What are you afraid of? Please specify this in the question so that we can try to answer this.

Comment: @Max Thank you.
If anybody else is looking for an answer, this view shows a ranked L.A. crime map: http://maps.latimes.com/neighborhoods/violent-crime/neighborhood/list/

Comment: @JoErNanO Violent crime ..

Comment: What is an *official no go zone*, if not an area where entrance is prohibited for civilians (which is probably not what you mean)?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Significantly higher, yes, but still far smaller than other risks such as traffic.

Comment: @gerrit I thought of an official recommendation for tourists by the city government or some tourism association.

Comment: @Antonio's map is excellent. Keep in mind that risk increases after dark and that you are perfectly safe (from crime) driving through those high-risk areas on freeways at any time of day. On surface streets, during the day, it may not look great but it's usually okay enough. Even the worst narrow part of Los Angeles is actually no worse than the average of all of Detroit. If you don't have a car- things may be a bit sketchier depending on where you have to go. Best to have a car.

Comment: Realistically, there aren't any 'no-go' zones like you now find in Europe.  Sure, there are areas that would be less ideal to transit, but merely driving down Crenshaw is not specifically dangerous.  I would worry more about getting mugged in West Hollywood or making a left turn on Santa Monica Blvd.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Honestly, driving a car here, if you're not accustomed to anything similar, probably carries a much greater likelihood of harm than violent crime... in most of the places visitors are likely to be spending time, anyway. The fact that things are spread out means you aren't too likely to wander on foot from a "friendly" area to an "unfriendly" one without putting some effort into it.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Yes, with some exceptions- it doesn't take long to get into sketchy areas from Little Tokyo, for example.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Fair enough, but I would still say it would be a reasonably unlikely accidental outcome of any kind of tourist activity. :)

Comment: [Some interesting statistics.](http://publichealth.lacounty.gov/ivpp/docs/Leading%20Cause%20Tables%200812%20and%200913/Leading%20Cause%20ED%202009%202013.pdf) (PDF file)

Answer (score 3):

According the LA Times the neighborhood called Chesterfield Square is the one with most violent crimes per capita as of spring 2017. Surrounding areas like Harvard Park or Vermont Vista and the Southcentral region in general rank high in violent crime statistics.

@Johns-305 Said in the comments that there is nothing like 'no-go' zones.

Thanks to @Max for providing the link to this site in the comments.

[Interactive Map of the L.A. Times](http://maps.latimes.com/neighborhoods/violent-crime/neighborhood/list/)

Los Angeles map showing neighborhoods ranked by violent crimes per capita 2016/17:
[image: Los Angeles map showing neighborhoods ranked by violent crimes per capita 2016/17]

Detail of Los Angeles map, showing Chesterfield Square:
[image: Detail of Los Angeles map, showing Chesterfield Square]

Comment: Do look at this area on a zoomable map that shows scale, though, to get a sense of the sheer distances involved. You aren't going to accidentally wander from Downtown to South Central. The closest you might get as a tourist would be visiting the Natural History Museum/La Brea tarpits.